# KNOCKOUT JS observableArray duplicate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

My html page is :

```
<div data-role="content">   
    <div id="menu">
        <ul id="menu" data-role="listview" class="ui-listview " 
            data-bind="foreach: menu">
            <li>
                <a data-bind="text:name, attr: {href: urlmenu}"></a>
                <a href="#"  data-bind="{ click: $parent.remove }" 
                   data-role="button" data-icon="delete"></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
     </div> 
</div>

<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
    <div data-role="navbar">
        <ul id="footer">
            <li><a href="#home" data-icon="home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Asignaturas" data-icon="grid">Asignaturas</a></li>
            <li><a href="#bandejaentrada" data-icon="mail">Mensajes</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my JS code is :

```
$( document ).on( "pagebeforechange" , function(e, data) {
      var toPage = data.toPage[0].id;

     if( toPage == "home"){
         ko.cleanNode(document.getElementById('menu'));
         menu();
     }
});

function menuViewModel(){
    var self = this;
    self.menu = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.menu.removeAll();
    self.menu = ko.observableArray([
                    new EditMenuViewModel("Perfil"),
                    new EditMenuViewModel("Asignaturas")
                ]);
}

function EditMenuViewModel(name) {
    this.name = ko.observable(name);
    this.urlmenu = ko.observable("#"+name);        
};    

function menu(){
    var menuviewModel = new menuViewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(menuviewModel, document.getElementById('menu'));       
}
```

When I load my page for the first time everything works fine, but when I click on link footer home, the array content is duplicated.

Example is here:

[image: First Load]

[image: after click footer home link]

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: What do you want to happen when the user clicks "Home"? Should the link list be rebuilt?

Comment: Yes, its a menu.  Menu and asignaturas only should be print

Answer (score 2):

You have two DOM elements with `id=menu`, a `div` and a `ul`.

```
<div id="menu"> <!-- <-- change this id for example -->
    <ul id="menu" data-role="listview" class="ui-listview " 
        data-bind="foreach: menu">
    ...
    </ul>
</div>
```

Ids should be unique, you need to change the id on one of your elements, hopefully this will also solve your problem.

### Update

As you can read in [this thread](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/912), `ko.cleanNode` will not remove items created using `foreach` binding.

You need to change your approach.

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nyothecat/QTWDx/) that reproduces your problem.

What you can do is stop cleaning+applying bindings, and update your observableArray instead:

```
$( document ).on( "pagebeforechange" , function(e, data) {
      var toPage = data.toPage[0].id;

     if( toPage == "home"){
         menuviewModel.menu.removeAll(); //clear menu
         //add whatever menu item you need
         menuviewModel.menu.push(new EditMenuViewModel("New Menu1 " + (new Date()).getTime()));
         menuviewModel.menu.push(new EditMenuViewModel("New Menu2 " + (new Date()).getTime()));
     }
});

function menuViewModel(){
    var self = this;
    self.menu = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.menu.removeAll();
    self.menu = ko.observableArray([
                    new EditMenuViewModel("Perfil"),
                    new EditMenuViewModel("Asignaturas")
                ]);
}

function EditMenuViewModel(name) {
    this.name = ko.observable(name);
    this.urlmenu = ko.observable("#"+name);        
};    

//bind only once
var menuviewModel = new menuViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(menuviewModel, document.getElementById('menu'));
```

Here is [an example](http://jsfiddle.net/nyothecat/QTWDx/2/)

Comment: No It hasn't changed and there aren't error in Js console! :(

Answer (score 0):

This is old thread, but I've found a (ugly) way to overcome it:
before the cleaning, I'm caching the observable array values and set it with only 1 value. After the rebind, I'm restoring the cached values. Something like this:

```
var self = this;
self.myArray = ko.observableArray(['val1', 'val2']);
var tempArray = [];
self.BeforeCleaning = function () {
    tempArray = self.myArray()
    self.myArray(['temp value']);
};

self.AfterRebinding = function () {
    self.myArray(tempArray);
};
```

horrible, but works for me.